# How to construct a query to filter data from a cloudant database using python?

Tags: python-3.x, cloudant

I am a complete novice in python. I have connected to a database in my cloudant account through python. I need to construct a query for filtering the data.

Here `x` is an `unixdate` object which i have calculated using the formula :-

```
s = str(datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=2))
x = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d").timestamp()
```

**Method 1**:

```
query = Query(my_database, selector={"type": "add", "uid": { "$gt": 0 }, "$_viewts": {"$gt": x }})
```

This query raises an HTTP error stating

> invalid operator for: $_viewts

**Method 2**:

```
query = Query(my_database, selector={"type": "add", "uid": { "$gt": 0 }, "_viewts": {"$gt": x }})
```

This query runs when I remove the `$` sign from the key `$_viewts` but produces an empty list as a result.

Any solutions/suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks

Comment: Please improve the formatting of this post, it's very hard to read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: I have formatted it. Please let me know if it requires further improvement. Thanks :)

Comment: You should use markdown as documented in that link, not HTML